# why the die() don't catch the fatal error?

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error, die

here is my code
(the database don't need password, but i intentionally added it to create the error)

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "null", "db") or die("Connection failed");
/*
if($connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","null","db")){
    print "Hello";
} else {
    print "Connection failed";
}
*/
```

?>

[when the page load it show only error handle and don't execute the die function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tilp4.png)

Comment: Because it's *fatal*?

Comment: mysqli_connect() only returns false if you're _not_ in exception mode, and exception mode is the default. If you want to enable true/false mode so that this `or` technique works, then you have to call [`mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php) first. (But note, you'll _still_ get a warning. So... just use exception mode with try/catch instead of this `or` technique.)

Comment: @user19626532 what you are getting is a *correct* behavior, while your die() is NOT. Just follow the answer linked at the top